# Про Стендаля, бухнувшегося в обморок

Tags: пунктуация

> Фигура Рафаэля, сама его личность, как сказали бы в учебнике, –
>   памятник эпохи <эпохЕ?> Возрождения. Ученик Умбрии! Он не первый предлагает
>   такую глубокую гармонию, но первый, кто так громогласно утверждает:
>   Бог, Человек и Мироздание – едины. А его гений – умение передать и
>   сложность внутренних переживаний, и фундаментальные идеи, и
>   хрустальную пронзительность религиозного чувства...
>
> **Невероятно – это я уже про Стендаля**. Какой размах. Какое глубокое
>   понимание другого художника с первого взгляда! Комплекс Стендаля…

Как оформить "невероятно"; тире мне мало, кавычек не хочу. Зап-тире? Оправданно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ответ исправлен.**

1) **Как выбрать падеж**: ***памятник эпохи*.**

Это **родительный определительный** (определяет и характеризует эпоху).

ПАМЯТНИК — 1. **кому (в честь кого-чего).** Памятник Пушкину в Москве; Памятник в честь основателя Петербурга Петра I;   3. **[то, что является ярким напоминанием о делах, трудах и т. п. кого-л., служит свидетельством чего-л.] чего.** Он [Словарь Российской Академии] останется вечным памятником... просвещенного **труда** наследников Ломоносова (П.).

**2) О памятнике эпохи**

Может ли человек быть памятником эпохи, то есть  ярким напоминанием  о ней? Не монументом, а памятником в переносном смысле? Но оказывается, **эта метафора уже не нова,** например: "Но прежней скудной жизни крохи Еще таятся по шкафам — **Бесценный памятник эпохи** — Слепой и рваный Мандельштам". 
https://www.bookol.ru/fantastika/alternativnaya_istoriya/79105/str2.htm

Сказал же Пушкин: "Я памятник себе воздвиг нерукотворный..." А еще Пушкин так говорил про Ломоносова: "Он создал первый университет. Он, лучше сказать, сам был **первым нашим университетом**". В переносном, конечно, значении.

Если перефразировать Пушкина, то можно составить такое предложение: Творчество Рафаэля — это выдающийся **памятник** эпохи Возрождения, да он и сам является  **памятником этой эпохи**.

При таком противопоставлении условность (переносное значение) слова *памятник* понятна, но в других случаях это надо бы как-то **обозначить**: заключить в кавычки или написать "своеобразный памятник" (это на вкус автора).

Теперь о тексте: **Фигура Рафаэля, сама его личность  – это блистательный  "памятник" эпохи Возрождения.**

В учебниках так, конечно, не говорят (эту фразу надо убрать). Чтобы подчеркнуть **метафоричность** сочетания, **можно подобрать определение,** которое к обычному памятнику не подходит.

3) **Невероятно (это я уже про Стендаля)!** Какой размах. Какое глубокое понимание другого художника с первого взгляда!

В скобках вставная конструкция (попутное замечание).

Comment: Почему, по-вашему, человек может быть памятником эпохи?

Comment: Потому что он характеризует эпоху, определяет ее. Для писателя это и его книги, и он сам как личность.

Comment: в таких случаях говорят: человек — эпоха, человек отражает эпоху, человек — символ эпохи. А выражения типа _Сталин — памятник эпохи_ звучат, по крайне мере для меня, плохо.

Comment: А я и не говорю, что мне нравится это выражение. Просто памятник эпохе звучит еще хуже, к тому же здесь некорректная грамматика.

Comment: вы не говорите, а надо бы. Исправляя грамматику или что бы то ни было, вы разрешаете другую ошибку.

Comment: Грамматической ошибки здесь нет. Что касается семантики, то это может быть авторским неологизмом, то есть употреблением слова в необычном значении. Выражение может нравиться или не нравиться, но я не стала бы считать это ошибкой. Вопрос был только о ПАДЕЖЕ, и я  определяла только правильность падежа, о чем сейчас и напишу

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вообще использовал скобочки. Они мне больше всего по душе, когда нужно оформить подобные предложения:

> Невероятно! (Это я уже про Стендаля.) Какой размах. Какое глубокое понимание другого художника с первого взгляда!

А с памятником вообще не ясно, что хотел сказать автор текста. Если эпохЕ, то бред. (Ср.: памятник Пушкину, то есть в память о Пушкине); если эпохИ, то при чем вообще тут слово памятник?

Comment: Вероятно, имеется ввиду "памятник/ времён/ эпохи Возрождения" .

Comment: @Сашка-дурак тогда эпохИ, но если Рафаэль — это ПАМЯТНИК, то автор, видимо, испанский летчик...

Comment: Памятник - не обязательно скульптурное изваяние. Здесь может подразумеваться не сам художник, как личность, а его творения, которые вполне могут являться памятниками той эпохи, когда они были созданы, то есть, произведёнными в ту эпоху.

Comment: @Сашка-дурак прочитайте текст: «__Фигура__ Рафаэля...»

Comment: Вы правы, разговор о личности. Всё равно, я считаю, именно "эпохи". Человек, как правило, - творение эпохи. Возьмите пример: нас с вами обучили обращаться с компьютерами, произошла ядерная война, мы выжили и стали живыми памятниками, произведёнными эпохой интернета(сохранили память этой эпохи).

Comment: С «памятником» автор переборщил. Есть нормальное слово Символ. И не Умбрия (это ж провинция), а Умбрийская школа.

Comment: Писатель как символ эпохи. Так принято говорить? А что такое символ? Это условный знак. Получаем: писатель как условный знак эпохи. Уж лучше так: писатель как памятный знак эпохи. Или так: Фигура Рафаэля, сама его личность, - это своеобразный памятник эпохи.

Comment: @Sharon предлагаю вам загуглить «символ эпохи», и вы найдете ответ. А подменять понятия бессмысленно.

Comment: Спасибо. Чтобы закончить наш диалог, я всё-таки позволю себе высказать личное мнение и символе эпохи и о теме вообще. Символ эпохи - это штамп, который так часто используется, что просто уже утомил. Значение у слова "символ" здесь тоже переносное, а любой перенос - это подмена понятий, "перенос наименования с одной реалии на другую". Вообще подменять понятия не рекомендуется, особенно не надо этого делать в научных текстах, но художественная речь метафорична по своей природе. Пожалуй, это всё. Мне правда жаль, что наши мнения по этому вопросу не совпали. Еще раз спасибо за внимание.